# Python looping through a list

Tags: python

This may be trivial for some but I have trouble looking through 2d array(?) in Python.

```
orderList = [ ('apples', 2.0), ('pears', 3.0), ('limes', 4.0) ]
```

How do I loop through this list? I've tried this but obviously it's not working.

```
for item in orderList:
        print item;
```

**If you can direct me to a tutorial or website that has this information, I will be content.

Comment: What output do you expect? What you have works...

Comment: Have you tried removing the semicolon?

Comment: @Ernir: The semicolon is redundant, not illegal

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use tuple unpacking to loop through everything:

```
for fruit, quantity in orderList:
    print 'I have', quantity, fruit + 'es'
```

You could also do this from inside of the `for` loop:

```
for fruit_info in orderList:
    fruit, quantity = fruit_info

    print 'I have', quantity, fruit + 'es'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works without any problem

```
orderList = [ ('apples', 2.0), ('pears', 3.0), ('limes', 4.0) ]
for item in orderList:
    print item;           #you don't need `;` but it is not a problem to leave it
>>>
('apples', 2.0)
('pears', 3.0)
('limes', 4.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to iterate over a list.

The most common is for each loop

```
for fruit in orderList:
    print fruit
```

A more efficient variation is using a generator, it's also worth noting that generators are iterable sequences.

```
def generator(fruits):
    for fruit in fruits:
        yield fruit

generate = generator(orderList)
firstFruit = generate.next()
// Doing complex calculations before continuing the iteration
answer = 21 + 21
secondFruit = generate.next()
```

A more elegant approach would be to use the higher-order function 'map'.  Map can also return a value. If you wanted to increase the price or quantity of each fruit by five percent you just have to make a simple function.

```
def display(fruit):
    print fruit  // map takes in a function as an argument and applies it to each element of the sequence.

map( display, orderList )

// You could also use a generator
map( display, generate )
```

The last way I can think of is using compression.  Compression is a built-in form of iteration thats now available in most standard library data structures.  It's useful if you want to make new list using a sequence.  I'm lazy, so I'm just reusing display to demostrate the syntax.

```
[ display(fruit) for fruit in orderList ]
[ display(fruit) for fruit in generate ]
```